# React & Draft.js - ConvertFromRaw not displaying "INLINETEX"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

I'm developing a `react` app, using `redux` and `electron`. As I was programming an editor with **INLINETEX** support along with `draft.js` and the [draft-js-mathjax-plugin](https://github.com/efloti/draft-js-mathjax-plugin), the necessity of saving my editor state showed up. So I'm converting the `ContentState` to Raw in order to save that state to a **database**:

```
const testContent = convertToRaw(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent())
```

And posteriorly converting it again to a `ContentState`:

```
const testState = EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(testContent))
```

With the `convertToRaw` and `convertFromRaw` methods, the **inline** style is lost, and only blocks of `TeX` can be created. That doesn't happen if no conversion is made. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This commonly occurs when you haven't set a onChange function to the component where you're trying to view the DraftJS. Try adding an onChange function to your Viewing component too. Once you're done with that, you'd also find that the mathjax plugin does not respect the readonly tag, at which point you'll have to do a workaround using CSS.